# Ne reCAPTCHA giving me a 403 error

Tags: php, recaptcha

Recently a client told me his website's reCAPTCHA was no longer working. After investigating, I found out that Google changed it. I upgraded their site using the new documentation from Nov 19, 2014, but it always gives me a 403 error.  I tried submitting just the secret key and that returned a JSON result with a false and an error. I did the same by just submitting the response from the g-recaptcha-response field and it also returned a JSON result with the error.  As soon as I put both of them into a string using http_build_query, I get a 403 forbidden from Google.

I am using the new http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify URL.  I am submitting to it using PHP cURL using the following code:

```
    $post_data = array('response'=>$response, 'secret'=>$privatekey);
    $curlPost = http_build_query($post_data, '', '&');

    $ch = curl_init();

    //Set the URL of the page or file to download.
    $url = 'http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlPost);

    $data_json = curl_exec($ch);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's your JSON result, exactly? (Also, I don't know much about reCAPTCHA, but from the looks of [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify), shouldn't you be using a GET request, rather than POSTing the parameters?)

Answer (score 6):

You have to use https, so the correct URL is:

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
```

This should fix the 403 error.

Comment: I am using https url : https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify but i am getting error **Tried all: 1 addresses, but could not connect over HTTPS to server: google.com port: 443**. I am using Java at server-side to validate the g-recaptcha-response string. What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: But then I get `could not open socket error` hahahhaha

Answer (score 0):

Just droping this info, as encountered and the reason was:
recaptcha gem starting from v5.0 changed used siteverify host from *google.com* to *recaptcha.net*
[code repo](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/blob/master/lib/recaptcha/configuration.rb#L36)

So might be needed configuration in FW.